# Rails user login is nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication

I have my rails app and when I try to login (I have created user called "test") I see this in the console:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"tlKwtMBNJ4LzJuJq13bUscAGpumdr+HVmUlGlfIudT9032DMXNxqa0d2VCxCvDZRDe1D6pFfaTafSRiL6tUvhw==", "session"=>{"login"=>"", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Log in"}
  User Load (1.7ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`login` IS NULL LIMIT 1
```

I see that in the session parameters application can't get user login (and maybe password too). Below are my user and session controllers:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    before_action :require_admin
    def new
        @users = User.new
    end
    def create
        @user = User.new(user_params)
        if @user.save 
            session[:user_id] = @user.id 
            current_user = @user.id

            redirect_to @user
        else 
            redirect_to '/login' 
        end 
    end
    private
    def user_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :login)
    end
end
```

Session controller:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

    def new
    end

    def create
        @user = User.find_by_login(params[:login])
        if @user && @user.authenticate(params[:password])
            session[:user_id] = @user.id
            redirect_to '/'
        else 
            flash[:error] = 'err'
            redirect_to '/login'
        end
    end

    def destroy
        session[:user_id] = nil 
        redirect_to root_url
    end
end
```

I have also tested the user creation and the record is in the database. 
@update here is my view for the login form

```
<%= form_for(:session, url: login_path) do |f| %> 
                    <div class="hidden-sm hidden-xs col-md-12 col-lg-12 ">
                        <%= f.text_field :login, :placeholder => "login" %> 
                        <%= f.password_field :password, :placeholder => "password" %> 
                        <%= f.submit "Log in", class: "btn-submit"%>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have nested hash in your params(`login` param is under `session` key).
Try

```
def create
  @user = User.find_by_login(params[:session][:login])
  if @user && @user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
    session[:user_id] = @user.id
    redirect_to '/'
  else 
    flash[:error] = 'err'
    redirect_to '/login'
  end
end
```

Also, in your example `login` param is empty - i guess it's not being supplied from the form.

@update: using form tag

```
<%= form_tag login_path, method: :post do %> 
  <div class="hidden-sm hidden-xs col-md-12 col-lg-12 ">
    <%= text_field_tag :login, :placeholder => "login" %> 
    <%= password_field_tag :password, :placeholder => "password" %> 
    <%= submit_tag "Log in", class: "btn-submit"%>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

and for create method(since params are not nested anymore):

```
def create
  @user = User.find_by_login(params[:login])
  if @user && @user.authenticate(params[:password])
    session[:user_id] = @user.id
    redirect_to '/'
  else 
    flash[:error] = 'err'
    redirect_to '/login'
  end
end
```

Comment: Ok it is still not working - I am using form_for in sessions#new view , should I try another method?

Comment: I have put my sessions/new view in my post

Comment: I guess it should work, but I've updated my answer with `form_tag` example
Just a sanity check - when you enter smth in login field and hit `submit` - what params server recieves?

Comment: now It is still does not working - I get no method error "undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass" in users_controller in line: @user = User.find_by_login(params[:session][:login]) also still I have no login i guess in the rails console

Comment: Sorry - I didn't properly update answer. Use just `params[:login]` and `params[:password]`

Comment: still null value in sql query

Comment: sorry, not null - 'users'.'login' = ''